# jQuery call to C# API controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have started some project based on ASP:NET MVC and JavaScript/jQuery. I am trying to make API call to my controller with `$.ajax` function, but I always get 404. I have Googled and tried a lot of different solutions, but again i get 404. I know this question is very often asked online, but again hope there won't be a lot of -1. I would appreciate any help, maybe I can't see tree because of forest.

Parameter "datas" is only string in JSON format.

My code is below:.

JavaScript call:

```
function checkValidId(datas) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/UserInfo/Test/',
        type: 'POST',        
        data: JSON.stringify(datas),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (valid) {
            if (valid) {
                console.log("HURAAAAY!!!");
            } else {
                console.log("OOOH NO YOU DON'T !!!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
public class UserInfoController : ApiController
    {
        private DM_DBEntities1 db = new DM_DBEntities1();

        [HttpPost]
        public static string Test(string data)
        {          
            return "H E L L L L O";
        }    
    }
```

My `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configured route is wrong.

Change it to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your Test method in UserInfoController need to return ActionResult regardless of if you're returning something to be recognised as an action method?